# Error in training an ANFIS model using frbs.learn() in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, rstudio, fuzzy

I am building an ANFIS model using frbs.learn() in R.
Here is my code:

```
library(readxl)
library(anfis)
library(parallel)
library(frbs)
Yamuna_final <- read_excel("F:/Downloads/Yamuna_final.xlsx",    
                         col_names = FALSE)
data.train <- as.matrix(Yamuna_final)

frbs_obj <- frbs.learn(data.train , range.data = NULL, method.type = 
    c("ANFIS"), list(num.labels = 13, max.iter= 10, step.size = 0.01, 
    type.tnorm = "MIN",                                                       
    type.implication.func = "ZADEH" , name = "Sim-0"))

test <- read_excel("F:/Downloads/test.xlsx",    
                       col_names = FALSE)
res <- predict(frbs_obj, test)
```

Now . when the frbs.learn() executes I get the error:

> Error in matrix(nrow = nrow(rule.data.num), ncol = 2 *
>   ncol(rule.data.num) -   : invalid 'ncol' value (< 0)

my dataset(data.train) has 1539 rows and 12 columns. A few instances of it are shown:

```
         X__1 X__2 X__3      X__4      X__5      X__6       X__7     X__8        X__9    X__10      X__11        X__12
    [1,] 1999    1    1  7.720000  11.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.92000        85.0 14.00000        210   8.60000000
    [2,] 1999    1    2  7.700000  10.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  2.00000        50.0 14.50000       3700  10.80000000
    [3,] 1999    1    3  8.400000  10.00000  1.000000  0.0400000  0.92000       120.0 23.00000        400   8.60000000
    [4,] 1999    1    4  8.270000   6.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.56000        80.0 22.00000       4600  12.50000000
    [5,] 1999    1    5  8.180000   6.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.80000       140.0 22.00000      23000   8.70000000
```

Now, my model is not getting trained and I am getting the above error. Don't know what's wrong. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be due to the presence of columns with only one unique value in your dataset.
In the code below, after deleting these columns, `frbs.learn` runs with no errors.

```
library(frbs)
data.train <- read.table(text="
         X__1 X__2 X__3      X__4      X__5      X__6       X__7     X__8        X__9    X__10      X__11        X__12
    [1,] 1999    1    1  7.720000  11.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.92000        85.0 14.00000        210   8.60000000
    [2,] 1999    1    2  7.700000  10.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  2.00000        50.0 14.50000       3700  10.80000000
    [3,] 1999    1    3  8.400000  10.00000  1.000000  0.0400000  0.92000       120.0 23.00000        400   8.60000000
    [4,] 1999    1    4  8.270000   6.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.56000        80.0 22.00000       4600  12.50000000
    [5,] 1999    1    5  8.180000   6.00000  1.000000  0.0500000  0.80000       140.0 22.00000      23000   8.70000000
", header=T)

# Find columns with only one unique value and delete them.
delete_cols <- apply(data.train, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))!=1)
data.train <- data.train[,delete_cols]

frbs_obj <- frbs.learn(data.train, range.data = NULL, method.type =c("ANFIS"), 
  list(num.labels = 13, max.iter= 10, step.size = 0.01, 
    type.tnorm = "MIN",                                                       
    type.implication.func = "ZADEH" , name = "Sim-0"))
```

Otherwise, the error may be due to the presence of `NA`s in the dataset.
Counting the number of missing data in the columns of your dataset, you can see that the second column has 1 missing value

```
apply(data.train,2,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

# X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 
#  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

at row 277

```
posNA <- which(apply(data.train,1,function(x) any(is.na(x))))
data.train[posNA, ]

#       X1 X2 X3   X4 X5 X6    X7    X8   X9 X10     X11 X12
# 277 2000 NA  1 7.49 77 25 13.17 19.26 5000  20 2.1e+07   0
```

Here is the final code:

```
library(frbs)
data.train <- read_excel("F:/Downloads/Yamuna_final.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)

posNA <- which(apply(data.train,1,function(x) any(is.na(x))))
data.train <- data.train[-posNA, ]
data.train <- as.matrix(data.train)

frbs_obj <- frbs.learn(data.train , range.data = NULL, method.type = 
    c("ANFIS"), list(num.labels = 13, max.iter= 10, step.size = 0.01, 
    type.tnorm="MIN", type.implication.func="ZADEH" , name="Sim-0"))
```

Comment: There is no column in my dataset that has just one unique value. The rows shown above are just a few instances.

Comment: @ShailyTyagi Inside `frbs.learn` there is the `frbs::norm.data` function that rescale dataset columns between 0 and 1. When a variabile has a 0 range, `norm.data` gives as output a column of `NAs`. This 'corrupted' dataset generates errors in the subsequent commands. Please, could you share your dataset privately ? I think that the error could be due to a problem with your dataset.

Comment: Sure!
Here is the link of my dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cSKkgPNREK7qStCZQMGQm7p9ZIPn5racovsh0EGyDVE/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks a lot

Comment: @ShailyTyagi Hi. I edited my answer. I found a missing values in the 2nd column of your dataset. Please, If you find useful my answer, please update and upvote. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to manually enter your min/max limits. Here it is with 0s for the mins:

```
range.data=matrix(c(0,1999,0,1,0,5,0,8.4,0,11,0,1,0,0.05,0,2,0
   ,140,0,23,0,23000,0,12.5),ncol=12)
```

This also allows frbs_learn to run without error.

Comment: I did this but now I am getting another error:
    in if (def[k, 1] > max(range.output)) def[k, 1] <- max(range.output) else if (def[k,  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed